# I Cant Build my app in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have Just Installed Android Studio In Ubuntu but when I try to put any View in XML I got this Problem !

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
>    Tip: Try to build the project.  The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:241)
>       at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:198)
>       at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.(WindowDecorActionBar.java:190)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:170)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:89)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:237)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:151)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:206)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>       at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>       at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Do u have any Solution !??

Comment: Try updating appcompat to the latest version (currently 23.1.1) and clean your project. You may need to fix imports as 2.3.1.1 moved internal packages.

Comment: @JaredRummler, you should post that as an answer.